# Error screen while test posting on UAT on Cornerstone OnDemand

Tags: upload, uat

Can anyone help me identify why this error might be occurring and how to resolve this?

We are testing the creation of tests on the UAT portal of CSOD (Cornerstone on demand) and this error comes randomly at any point during the process. We use excel files to copy paste contents for the test, there are 3-4 sheets in a file. At a time only 2 people at max at working on the UAT.

Thanks!

Error screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Where is the Screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2CJy.jpg